# How to find out how a program started on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, task-manager, automatic-update

From what I have understood after researching on Google, there are two ways of how a program can start on Windows:

1. Manual (The user doubled clicked on the executable or shortcut file of the program)
2. Automatic:
3. Started by another program

Automatic startup can be due to 4 reasons:

- A service, that should be installed
- the windows registry
  (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)
- a shortcut to it to the startup folder of start menu
- task scheduler

However, I found an invisible window called:  **UNCServer.exe** running on my computer.

I want to stop it but I couldn't find the reason why it is running. I checked everywhere on all the bullets points mentioned above but there is no luck.

Assuming that the task is running right now on my computer, is there a way to know how a program has started on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. Here is what I did:

I decided that I am going to rename the file to bak-uncserver.exe because if it is a program that starts it, I will cause a error. I restarted my PC and indeed, the error popup appeared saying that the file uncserver.exe was not found. Then looking at the task manager, the popup was shown by a program called tvsu.exe which was located in the same directory as uncserver.exe. The conclusion is it is that tvsu file that started uncserver.

Then I checked both services and autostart. tvsu was an automatic servic. I disabled it. Then restarted. However, the windows popup still appeared.

Finally, after digging,  I checked task scheduler under 'Task Scheduler Library'. I found TVT>TVSUUPdate task:
[image]

I disabled it. It is finally gone. It was a task scheduled

Answer (score 5):

If you would use [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), you can find how program started:
From menu: go to `View->Select column` then switch to tab:`Process Image`
and check box <kbd>Autostart location</kbd>.

This way you can reveal what mechanism program used to autostart.
Make sure to run  [ProcessExplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) as administrator.

Comment: Even the `Command line`option is great

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) tool of [Windows Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) for this purpose.

On executing this tool, it will list everything which is automatically executed on your system. You can use search and filter to find what is causing **UNCServer.exe** to run on your system.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, uncserver.exe is not listed

Comment: @TSR This executable is part of `Lenovo System Update`. Main executable is `tvsu.exe`; These executable can be found in `C:\Program Files\lenovo\system update` folder. If you do not want to run system updates from manufacturer, you may disable or uninstall it completely.

Comment: are you saying that `uncserver.exe` is launched by `tvsu.exe` ? If so, what is launching `tvsu.exe`

Answer (score 1):

> However, I found an invisible window called: UNCServer.exe running on my computer.
>
> I want to stop it but I couldn't find the reason why it is running. I checked everywhere on all the bullets points mentioned above but there is no luck.

It's located in the following directory:

`C:\Program Files\Lenovo\System Update\`

In order to remove it, you should remove `ThinkVantage System Update`, and reboot your system.  UNCserver.exe is system update(Universal Naming Convention) server module.  It runs as a separate windows task while `ThinkVantage System Update` is running.  Since the software is only installed, if you installed the Lenovo software, you can safely remove it.

Considering Lenovo has been known to break the internet by installing insecure self-signed certificates, and running a Man In the Middle attack on all secure traffic, you should remove **ALL** Lenovo software from your machine.